# Doctrine : Generate Reference number from ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, lifecycle

I have a field called "`refNo`" in an object called "`Job`", this number is created by putting the **state initials** and the **id + 2023**. Meaning, if this job is done in California, and the id of this object is 2, the refNo would have to be: `CA-2025`.

I have this code:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
    $this->refNo = $this->state . '-'. ($this->id + 2023);
    }
```

This would make everybody's id CA-2023, meaning the id is not getting generated before this is created. I've tried doing using these `@HasLifecycleCallbacks: prePersist , postPersist , preFlush , onFlush`  in this way:

```
/**
 * @PostPersist 
 */
public function jobNo()
{
  $this->jobNo =  $this->id + 2286;
}
```

No luck. Anyway how I can achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create an entity in the DB and it gets ID assigned. Then your `@PostPersist` method gets called and sets `jobNo`. However, you don't `flush` again after it so even though your `jobNo` **is set**, you never actually save it in the database.

The solution is to re-save it again in the database afterwards.

Comment: Is there a way where I wouldnt need to do that? I really wouldnt want to do one flush after the other.

Comment: No, only way is if you don't make ID an autogenerated value - meaning that you assign it manually. That way you will know what the id is before you save entity to database. Otherwise, since database creates it, there is no way to pull that off without saving twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a separate event listener to generate code(s) for various entities. This is simplified example that evokes `$entity->generateRef();` after entity is created.

```
<?php

namespace Example\CommonBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class CodeAssembler
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $classes = array(
            'Example\CommonBundle\Entity\Job',
        );

        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (in_array(get_class($entity), $classes)) {
            $entity->generateRef();
            $args->getEntityManager()->flush();    
        }
    }
}
```

Attach event listener:

```
# services.yml
example_common.code_assembler_listener:
        class: Example\CommonBundle\EventListener\CodeAssembler
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```